# How can I create a bootable SD card with linux kernel?

Tags: arm, linux

I just order an ARM Cortex A8 development board with preinstalled Android, but instead of the preinstalled OS I would like to use Linux, so I compiled the kernel with success, but I don't know how can I create a bootable SD card with the Linux OS. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Isnt this should be ask in superuser?

Comment: @blackandyello - there are probably too many hardware-unique details of the boot process for that.  Kicsci will probably need to look for someone else's writeup (consider generic allwinner projects?), or spend some time exploring the board under android to get an idea of how things work - it would be good to be familiar with how "standard" android devices boot, as well as some of the alternative schemes which have been used, for example on versions of the nook color which could boot off of an sdcard.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You (most likely) need a bootloader on the SD-card. Something like [u-boot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/u-boot/), [qi](http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Qi) or even [grub](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/). Make sure your bootloader can read the filesystem on your SD card.
2. You have to mark your partition bootable with a tool like [cfdisk](http://www.gnu.org/software/fdisk/).

Partition your SD card if needed. Put the bootloader, kernel & root filesystem on it and of you go (hopefully).